# Как ускорить код работы программы?

Tags: python

Определите количество принадлежащих отрезку [2 · 10^10; 4 · 10^10] натуральных чисел, которые делятся на 7 и на 100 000 и при этом не делятся на 13, 29, 43 и 101, а также наименьшее из таких чисел. В ответе запишите два целых числа без пробелов и других дополнительных символов: сначала количество, затем наименьшее число.

```
m = 4 * 10**10 +1
k=0
for i in range(2 * 10**10,4 * 10**10 +1):
    if i %7==0 and i %100000==0 and i %13!=0 and i %29!=0 and  i %43!=0 and i %101!=0:
        k +=1
        if i<m:
            m=i
print(k,m)
```

в IDLE запускаю и просто выдачи ответа не дождаться, как ускорить можно было бы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если чуть-чуть подумать, то `2 * 10**10` конечно делится на `100000` нацело (там ведь 10 нулей в конце). А какое следующее число будет делиться на `100000` нацело? Конечно же `2 * 10**10 + 100000`. А следующее? Таким образом, просто нужно перебирать не все числа подряд, а с шагом `100000`. И у `range` для такого перебора есть специальный третий параметр. Ответ получается моментально.